# Trying to change the position of characters of two different numbers

Tags: java, android

I was trying to do an exercise which is "Type 2 numbers and each character in a pair position swap it with the equivalent of the character in the same position of the second number, and the characters in an impair position swap them with the character in the same position of the first number"

But I haven't worked with characters before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, this is the code i have so far, it throws random stuff out instead of the numbers changed.
I have this code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtNum1, edtNum2;
    TextView txvRes;
    Button btnEjecutar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnEjecutar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEjecutar);
        btnEjecutar.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener ButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txvRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvRes);
            int a, b;
            char[] n1, n2;
            edtNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNum1);
            edtNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNum2);
            a = Integer.parseInt(edtNum1.getText().toString());
            b = Integer.parseInt(edtNum2.getText().toString());
            char [] chars1 = String.valueOf(a).toCharArray();
            char [] chars2 = String.valueOf(b).toCharArray();

            if(chars1.length > chars2.length){
                for(int i = 0;i < chars2.length;i++){
                    if(i % 2 != 0){
                        chars2[i] = chars1[i];
                    }else if(i % 2 == 0){
                        chars1[i] = chars2[i];
                    }
                }
            }else if(chars1.length < chars2.length){
                for(int i = 0;i < chars1.length;i++){
                    if(i % 2 != 0){
                        chars2[i] = chars1[i];
                    }else if(i % 2 == 0){
                        chars1[i] = chars2[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            n1 = chars1;
            n2 = chars2;
            txvRes.setText("the first number is: "+n1+" and the second number is: "+n2);
        }
    };}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend stepping through this with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

> Type 2 numbers and each character in a odd position swap it with the
>   equivalent character in the same position of the second number, and
>   the characters in an odd position swap them with the character in the
>   same position of the first number

If you're gonna overwrite odd positions and even positions, your end numbers will be the same ?

In the case that you swap they will be the same numbers but reversed. Would you post an input and output cases of what you want to achieve ?

In any case, you don't need to create an if for length.

```
        int minLength = Math.min(chars1.length, chars2.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
            } else {
            }
        }
```

Plus num modulus 2 has only 2 outcomes, 1 or 0, so you don't need another if in that condition.
Also in your current code it's not executing if the length is the same. That may cover some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the way to fix it, first of all i was using char array in the setText which caused to output a weird string of characters

Second, i was basically changing the values wrong in the function because when i changed the first one i was replacing the value of the first one that i had previously, meaning that both numbers would end up with the same characters instead of being swapped at certain positions.

Here's the fixed code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtNum1, edtNum2;
    TextView txvRes;
    Button btnEjecutar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnEjecutar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEjecutar);
        btnEjecutar.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener ButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txvRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvRes);
            int a, b;
            char[] chars3, chars4;
            edtNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNum1);
            edtNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNum2);
            a = Integer.parseInt(edtNum1.getText().toString());
            b = Integer.parseInt(edtNum2.getText().toString());
            char [] chars1 = String.valueOf(a).toCharArray();
            char [] chars2 = String.valueOf(b).toCharArray();
            chars3 = chars1;
            chars4 = chars2;
            if(chars1.length > chars2.length){
                for(int i = 0;i < chars2.length;i++){
                    if(i % 2 != 0){
                        chars2[i] = chars3[i];
                        chars1[i] = chars4[i];
                    }else if(i % 2 == 0){
                        chars1[i] = chars4[i];
                        chars1[i] = chars3[i];
                    }
                }
            }else if(chars1.length < chars2.length){
                for(int i = 0;i < chars1.length;i++){
                    if(i % 2 != 0){
                        chars2[i] = chars3[i];
                        chars1[i] = chars4[i];
                    }else if(i % 2 == 0){
                        chars1[i] = chars4[i];
                        chars2[i] = chars3[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            String c = new String(chars1);
            String d = new String(chars2);
            txvRes.setText("El primer Numero es: "+c+" y el segundo Numero es: "+d);
        }
    };
}
```